# Creating a footnote in a paper title

Tags: footnotes, titles

I'm trying to create a footnote in my document title, but coming a bit unstuck - the document starts as so:

```
\documentclass{acm_proc_article-sp}
\begin{document}

\title{This is my title\footnote{Just a note.}}
```

I get a dot after the title, presumably the footnote indicator, but the footnote text is nowhere to be seen.

Could anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Can you not use \thanks{Just a note.} instead?

Comment: @cfr Yes, that works - sorry, was unaware that that could be used in the paper title (I thought it was just for authors.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is fully related to this custom class you are using. In the version that I found on the web the `\maketitle` macro does not execute

```
\let\footnote\thanks
```

as the standard classes do. You could, *of course*, use the `\thanks` macro (directly) or add two tiny lines of code to your preamble:

```
\documentclass{acm_proc_article-sp}
\let\ACMmaketitle=\maketitle
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{\begingroup\let\footnote=\thanks \ACMmaketitle\endgroup}
\begin{document}
\title{This is my title\footnote{Just a note.}}
\author{berry120}
\maketitle
Hello\footnote{World}
\end{document}
```

The choice is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is using `acmart`, the ACM Article Template, note that you can't use `\thanks` in the title. Use `\titlenote` instead.

```
\title{This is a title}
\titlenote{This is a titlenote}
```

Read the [documentation](https://www.acm.org/binaries/content/assets/publications/consolidated-tex-template/acmart.pdf) for more information.

I spent some time realizing that I can't use `\thanks`. Since this article ranked first in Google, I post this answer and hope it helps anyone struggling with the ACM template. Sorry for bumping up the old question.